# Задержка TcpClient в Delphi7

Tags: delphi-7

При проверке порта своего сервера мне нужно поставить задержку при ответе, чтоб клиент не зацикливался на ожидании ответа сервера если порт допустим закрыт, а продолжал дальше проверять,мне надо ускорить процесс сканирования портов моего сервера,как это сделать подскажите.

Пример кода :

```
//как сюда поставить задержку,как это реализуется?
tcp.RemoteHost := diap.Strings[s];
tcp.Open;
if tcp.Connected then
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В инструкций, что то выполняйте, к примеру

```
if tcp.Connected then
begin
 Memo1.Lines.Add('Ура порт открыт');
end;
```

и следующая инструкция она в любом случаи отработает, вне зависимости открыт порт или нет

```
tcp.Close; //Закрываем порт или соединение
```

Можно попробовать в блоке try except.

p.s. наберите в поисковиках "сканер портов delphi 7", вариантов тьма.

Касательно скорости сканирования, простыми способами сделать не получится.

**Установка TCP сессии**

Клиент посылает TCP сегмент с битом (флагом) SYN и с 32 битным заполненным полем "Порядковый номер"  с номерами портов DST (Порт назначения) и SRC (Порт источника), сервер к значению поля "Порядковый номер" прибавляет "1"   и заполняет поле "Номер подтверждения", устанавливает бит ASK и отправляет клиенту, клиент снимает бит SYN добавляет "1" к полю "Номер подтверждения" и отправляет серверу, всё TCP сессия установлена.

Если проще то происходит так "клиент -> сервер", "сервер -> клиент", "клиент->сервер".

Закрытие **активного** соединения происходит аналогично, только с битом FIN.

Компоненты Delphi работают по  выше изложенной  "схеме". Избежать 3 этапа (клиент-> сервер) умеет сканер Nmap. Nmap определяет открыт порт или нет без полного соединения только на анализе второго пакета с SYN и ASK.